# How to aggregateSUM all keyvalues(=cost) from a field(payment) (one to one relationship) of all model(Session)

Tags: django, django-queryset

I would like to traverse a (one to one relationship) field of session. Specifically the payment
and for each Session-payment aggregate Sum all the payment.cost
Something like for each session-payment (if payment exists) aggrSum all the cost VALUES.

in my views.py (sthing gotta change)

```
  "TotalCost": (
     sessions.values_list("payment").aggregate(Sum("cost"))
  ),
```

models.py. (these are my stable files)

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    payment_req = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    cost = models.FloatField(blank=True, validators=[validate_positive])

    invoice = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # session_id = models.OneToOneField(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

```
class Session(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)

    payment = models.OneToOneField(Payment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    user_comments_ratings = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Id = {self.id}"
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. What exactly would you be aggregating? Each `Session` instance has one `Payment` instance which has a field `cost`. So for each `Session` there is only one `cost` so aggregating really doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Aggregate Sum all of the costs